# What is the demonym for a citizen of Niger?

Tags: single-word-requests, demonyms

If a citizen of [Nigeria](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Nigeria/@7.8008631,10.7648591,6z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x104e0baf7da48d0d:0x99a8fe4168c50bc8) is a Nigerian, what is a citizen of [Niger](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Niger/@17.5968801,8.0828506,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x1199ec7ac6a1af5d:0xc933920a158e24d4) referred to as?

The [Wikipedia article on Niger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niger) and the online [Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/nigerien) say that the proper term is *Nigerien*, as Vogel612 points out below. But *The New York Times Manual of Style and Usage* (1999) and *Merriam-Webster’s Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) say that the proper name is *Nigerois*. And [Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/niger) now lists both *Nigerien* and *Nigerois* as correct forms. Is this simply a terminological difference between U.S. (or North American) English and British English, or is one word truly more appropriate than the other?

Comment: Please note that general references disagree about the correct answer to this question.

Comment: From a web search, it appears that NY Times' last use of "Nigerois" was in 2011 - the term "Nigerien" appears in more recent articles. Don't know if that indicates a change in their style book since the edition cited above. Also noted that Canada's TERMIUM lexicon (FR & EN) demoted Nigerois in English to "obsolete" in 2013 (it does not appear in French). Of possible interest is a Wikipedia user page started in 2013. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:A12n/Nigerois

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The English Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niger) lists *Nigerien* (/niːˈʒɛəriən/).

Usually the guys over there are good with such stuff so I'd trust them with this one.

This is also backed up by the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/nigerien) and Wiktionary.

Comment: There's been a substantial edit to the question since this answer was given.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I am well aware :) Unfortunately I neither have the experience of the other answerers, so it's near impossible for me to write such all-comprising answers. Also I wouldn't want to take anything from their excellent research.

Comment: There is the unfortunate fact that "Nigerien" is essentially indistinguishable from "Nigerian" when spoken.  There might be a subtle difference, but the listener would not recognize it unless listening very carefully.

Comment: @HotLicks: So "He comes from Niger" or "he is a citizen of Niger" might be preferable of you want to actually inform a listener where that person comes from.

Comment: Could you say "he is a Nigerien from Niger"? Just to make sure everyone knows what you are talking about?

Comment: @HotLicks You must be pronouncing either _Nigerian_ or _Nigerien_ very differently from how I pronounce them, then. I pronounce _Nigeria(n)_ as /naɪˈʤɪəɹiə(n)/ _nye-JEER-ee-uh(n)_, while _Niger(ien)_ is /niːʒεːɹ(iən)/ _nee-ZHER(-ee-uhn)_ (as also given on the Wikipedia page). They sound completely different and no one—not even someone who knew no English—could possibly confuse the two.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- In the US "Niger" is pronounced pretty much the same as the first two syllables of "Nigeria", with a J sound, not a Z sound.

Answer (score 8):

When I find multiple conflicting usages, I like to see what other people are using. The NGrams data clearly shows a vast preference for *Nigerien*. A [slate.com article which claims to have verified its facts with the Nigerien Embassay in the US](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2003/07/how_do_you_pronounce_niger.html) says

> What do you call someone who hails from Niger? Old-schoolers (and, in what an editor there called "something of an oversight," the Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary) still use the archaic "Nigerois" (nee-zher-WAH); more common and up-to-date is "Nigerien" (nee-ZHER-yen).

An NYT columnist who wrote an article about Nigeriens, [was told by his editor that the NYT style manual prefers *Nigerois* to avoid confusion with *Nigerians*.](http://kristof.blogs.nytimes.com/2005/10/11/?_r=0) But while in Niger he was told that nobody uses that word and so decided to stick with *Nigeriens*.

So stick with *Nigerien*, unless you are happy to sound archaic for the purpose of preventing confusion.

--

[Google Ngrams gives the following usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nigerien%2CNigerois%2CNigeran&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNigerien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNigerois%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNigeran%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

If you wish to break it down by US/BR differences, you can:

**[US](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nigerien%2CNigerois%2CNigeran&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNigerien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNigerois%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNigeran%3B%2Cc0):**

[image]

**[BR](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nigerien%2CNigerois%2CNigeran&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNigerien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNigeran%3B%2Cc0):**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

***Differing opinions***

As the question notes, different references have different opinions about the merits of *Nigerien* versus *Nigerois*. As Vogel 612 observes, both Wikipedia and the online *Oxford Learner's Dictionary* endorse *Nigerien*. In addition, the [*World Fact Book*](http://books.google.com/books?id=K0kXAQAAMAAJ&q=%22nigerien%22&dq=%22nigerien%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jLBrVPaOBsP-iALM34CIBg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwCDha) (1997), the *New Oxford American Dictionary* (2001), the *New Oxford American Dictionary and Thesaurus with Language Guide* (2003) offer only *Nigerien* as the word for the people of Niger. The *Concise Oxford English Dictionary*, Revised Tenth Edition (2001), is noncommittal: It includes an entry for the noun *Nigerian* ("a native or inhabitant of Nigeria") doesn't offer any advice on what to call "a native or inhabitant of Niger."

On the other hand *The New York Times Manual of Style and Usage* (1999) has this:

> **Nigerois** (sing. and pl.) The people of Niger, The adjective is *Niger*. Do not confuse with *Nigeria* and *Nigerians*, for the larger country and its people.)

The [U.S. Government Printing Office Style Manual](http://books.google.com/books?id=JDFqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22nigerois%22&dq=%22nigerois%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EbVrVI_7BMr_igKVioDQBg&ved=0CEUQ6AEwCTgo) (1984)—which gives "Nigerois (singular, plural)," though you may not be able to see anything in the online snippet view of this book—Robert Harris & American Heritage Dictionary, [*Secretary's Handbook*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Z44YAAAAIAAJ&q=%22nigerois%22&dq=%22nigerois%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GbZrVJC1F6-9iQLM0oDIBQ&ved=0CCEQ6AEwATgy) (1984), Robert Grover, [*U.S. News & World Report Guidelines for Writers and Editors*](http://books.google.com/books?id=cjSCR3DwPBEC&q=%22nigerois%22&dq=%22nigerois%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1o5rVOmLNcSbigLSuoD4Bg&ved=0CEoQ6AEwCTgU) (1994), Amy Einsohn, [*The Copyeditor's Handbook: A Guide for Book Publishing and Corporate Communications*](http://books.google.com/books?id=93i4WNp9ZtYC&pg=PA157&dq=nigerois&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OrFrVO3cMNHViALojYGICg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=nigerois&f=false) (2000), and Patti Tasko, [*The Canadian Press Stylebook: A Guide for Writing and Editing*](http://books.google.com/books?id=B1Nv2vQ5bRIC&q=%22nigerois%22&dq=%22nigerois%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1o5rVOmLNcSbigLSuoD4Bg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwCDgU) (2006) likewise give only *Nigerois* as the name to use for the people of Niger. To my surprise, the *Associated Press Stylebook* (2002) doesn't offer any guidance on what to call the people of different nations.

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) lists only *Nigerois*, but the [online version of MW's entry for *Niger*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/niger) broadens the options to *Nigerien* and *Nigerois*:

> — **Nigerien** *adjective or noun*
>
> — **Nigerois** *noun*

Interestingly, MW online doesn't offer *Niger* as an adjective form of the country Niger, whereas the *New York Times* instructs its writers to use only that form as an adjective.

---

***Arguments for 'Nigerien'***

I am aware of four arguments that others have made for preferring *Nigerien* to *Nigerois*. First and most impressively (see the Ngram charts posted by
Mr. Shiny and New 安宇 in his answer), *Nigerien* dominates current usage.

Second, as Slate Magazine's *The Explainer* (2004) argues in a commentary on Niger, the term *Nigerois* is "archaic":

> Until 1960, Niger was a colony of France, and French is still Niger' official language. Its neighbor Nigeria, with which it is occasionally confused, was under English control before it gained its independence, also in 1960; that's why the pronunciations differ so sharply. What do you call someone who hails from Niger? Old-schoolers (and, in what an editor there called “something of an oversight,” the *Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary*) still use the archaic *Nigerois* (nee-zher-WAH); more common and up-to-date is *Nigerien* (nee-ZHER-yen).

Third, according to a fairly detailed [Wikipedia user page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:A12n/Nigerois) posted by User:A12n, *Nigerois* is a made-up term with no historical legitimacy other than the fact that some people have used it:

> **Nigerois** is a coined term of French construction that is not actually a word in the French language, but has had some use in English to refer to people from Niger, West Africa.

And fourth, referring to an October 11, 2005, ["On the Ground" blog item](http://kristof.blogs.nytimes.com/2005/10/11/?_r=1) by *New York Times* editorial columnist Nicholas Kristof—again cited in Mr. Shiny and New 安宇's answer—it may be argued that since "the people here [in Niger]" don't use the term *Nigerois*, English speakers not in Niger shouldn't use it either.

---

***Arguments for 'Nigerois'***

The strongest argument in favor of *Nigerois*—and undoubtedly the reason that U.S. periodicals like *U.S. News & World Report* and the *New York Times* adopted the term—is that it puts maximum distance between the names for the people of Niger and the people of Nigeria. Dixie Wills, [*New World Order: Every Country on Earth, Sorted*](http://books.google.com/books?id=1ivxqywAif0C&q=%22nigerois%22&dq=%22nigerois%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D7drVILHFJfkoATbloHADA&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAzhG) (2008) puts the case (rather obnoxiously) this way:

> **Pub fact:** For decades, the pubs, bars and discotheques of the world have resounded to the debate, often quite heated, surrounding the adjectival form of Niger. Go for 'Nigerian' and everyone thinks you're referring to Nigeria; opt for 'Nigerois' and no one knows what you're talking about; while plumping for plain old 'Niger' just doesn't sound right. Apparently, the answer is to aim at a noise approximating to 'Nigérien'. Good luck.

Obnoxious or not, Wills did enough research to discover that the River Niger owes it name to the Tuareg word *n'eghirren* (which she says means "flowing water"). On the other hand, she failed to notice that, virtually unanimously, the institutional proponents of *Nigerois* recommend using it only as a noun referring to the people of Niger, not as an adjective.

To (some) North Americans, the pattern of the word *Nigerois* is immediately recognizable as matching that of *Quebecois* (a native of Quebec), so it isn't an altogether outlandish formulation. But its difference from the noun *Nigerian* is the term's preeminent virtue.

The other arguments on behalf of *Nigerois* are perhaps more accurately characterized as attempts to counter the arguments in favor of *Nigerien*.

Regarding the massive advantage that *Nigerien* enjoys in popular usage, the counterargument is that *Nigerois* is predominantly a noun, whereas *Nigerien* piles up the vast majority of its matches in a Google Books search as an adjective. Since the Ngram charts that show the overwhelming relative frequency of *Nigerien* don't isolate occurrences of that word as a noun, they aren't terribly relevant to the question of how *Nigerois* as a noun and *Nigerien* as a noun match up.

As for the assertion that *Nigerois* is archaic, it's worth noting that the majority of the 97 Google Books search matches for *Nigerois* are from the the period between 1990 and 2014. The totals are 34 from the 29-year period of 1961–1989, and 63 from the 25-year period of 1990–2014. That hardly suggests the timeline distribution of an archaic term. The oldest instance is exceedingly old—from U.S. Department of Defense, [*Africa Names and Concepts*](http://books.google.com/books?id=lk9HAQAAIAAJ&q=%22nigerois%22&dq=%22nigerois%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D7drVILHFJfkoATbloHADA&ved=0CEAQ6AEwCDhG) (1961)—but only a handful of others come from the 1960s.

It's also worth pointing out that the sentence following the one from the Slate Explainer article that Mr. Shiny and New 安宇's answer quotes says this:

> Still both [*Nigerien* and *Nigerois*] are acceptable, as long as you don't call your friend in Niamey a *Nigerian*.

Neither the criticism of *Nigerois* based on its etymological origin nor the one based on its nonuse in Niger seems especially compelling—unless we are determined to adopt a comparable test for the names we use in English for other nationalities of the world.

---

***A quick look at 'Nigeran'***

The Ngram charts posted by Mr. Shiny and New 安宇 that track the word *Nigeran* are intriguing, but unfortunately they, too, run afoul of a confounding variable—in this case, the water-soluble polymer (or fungal wall glucan) nigeran. Of the 27 matches from the period 1985–1987 in a Google Books search for *Nigeran*, 18 were to the polymer, and 9 were (arguably) to the adjective form of *Niger*. I say "arguably" because three of the latter group appear in publications titled *Nigerian Economy: A Textbook of Applied Economics* (1986), *Equity and Trusts in Nigeria* (1986), and *Nigerian Journal of Palms and Oil Seeds* (1987)—and in each case, the book contained only one match for *Nigeran*, suggesting that these instances might have involved typos for *Nigerian*. The remaining six instances were far from obviously Niger-related either; but when you're dealing with snippet views, the necessary context can be hard to come by.

Almost certainly the reason *Nigeran* didn't catch on as the adjective form of *Niger* is that typos and typesetting mistakes of this very kind were a constant danger. Several of the matches from the 1960s and 1970s clearly use *Nigeran* as an adjective for *Niger*; but in the 100 matches for *Nigeran* for the period 1972–1993, I couldn't find a single instance where *Niger* was unmistakably intended. Most matches were for the chemical *nigeran*, and many of the rest were clearly typos for *Nigerian*.

One nice thing about this search data for *Nigeran* is that it shows what a term that truly is archaic looks like in Google Books search results: Almost all of the matches turn out to be mismatches of one kind or another.

---

***Conclusion***

Ultimately, even though I don't find any of the four asserted arguments on behalf of *Nigerien* particularly persuasive, I would probably use it in preference to *Nigerois*, for two reasons. First, I am impressed that Merriam-Webster's online has switched from "*Nigerois* only" to "*Nigerois* and *Nigerien*" in the past decade. I don't believe that the Google Books evidence supports a claim that *Nigerois* is obsolescent or archaic, but I do think that *Nigerien* as a noun is gaining ground—and as an adjective it clearly enjoys a massive advantage, since the advocates of *Nigerois* generally don't recommend using it as an adjective at all.

Second—and more compelling, to my mind—I think that the rationale for avoiding *Nigerien* wasn't simply that the word looks a lot like *Nigerian*. It was also, to some extent, the fact that publishers didn't trust their audience to know that any such place as Niger existed. If you see *Nigerien* and you know only Nigeria as a country with a relevant-looking name, you're likely to suppose that *Nigerien* is a form of *Nigeria*. But thanks to the U.S. government's yellow-cake uranium fiasco of the mid-2000s and the attention now being paid to that area of West Africa and the area just south of it, many more English-speaking readers today are aware that Niger exists; and as a result fewer people by default associate *Nigerien* with *Nigeria* than was once the case. *Niger* as an adjective may still be common, but (in a situation mirroring *Nigerien* as a noun versus *Nigerien* as an adjective) those instances tend to get lost in the forest of instances of *Niger* as a noun.

The more frequently people use and recognize *Nigerien* as a noun or as an adjective associated with Niger and not Nigeria, however, the less reason anyone has to adhere to *Nigerois*. That reality doesn't make the latter term a living fossil, but it does suggest that the historical direction of usage is against it. The only complication hindering *Nigerien* in its progress toward universal adoption in English is its susceptibility to hard-to-catch typographical error—a practical problem that may keep *Nigerois* in the *New York Times Manual of Style* and other style guides for years to come.

Comment: I don't think we need to adopt etymological or local usage tests for all exonyms, but surely when there is disagreement such things should factor into decisions? Nobody seems to care that we call it "China" and they call it "Zhongguo" but if there were differing opinions about what to call it, shouldn't the fact that they call it "Zhongguo" be relevant? If China was disbanded today and a dozen new states sprung up, we'd need names for each of them, and I bet their local names would go a long way towards determining what our new words would be.