# Nigerian vs. Nigerien

Tags: word-choice

A few days ago was the first time I ran into the word "Nigerien" meant to mean "something related to the African country of Niger" as opposed to "Nigerian" meaning "something related to the African country of Nigeria".

Since this is very easily confused, for example by my spelling checker which didn't like "Nigerien" at all, and especially in spoken English, is that use actually correct, or is there a better word? And how would you pronounce it so that it doesn't get confused? (With the countries themselves, I thought NIger has an emphasis on the first syllable, and NiGERia on the second, but for Nigerien this sounds just wrong to me).

Comment: Niger was formerly administered by France, so the name is pronounced as in French (nee-zhaire) and the adjective, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nigerien) takes the French spelling (c.f. _italien_). Very confusing that it's so similar to _Nigerian_.

Comment: They just had a military coup and the “Nigerien” “government” is trying to throw out the French embassador. Who is now locked inside the embassy.

Comment: Closely related: [What is the demonym for a citizen of Niger?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208692/what-is-the-demonym-for-a-citizen-of-niger)

Comment: The current political situation does not affect the fact that French is the main non-African language in use in the country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used both and both are in the OED

The relevant pronunciations are quite distinct

Nigerien (dates from 1966) : /nɪˌʒɛːrɪˈɛn/ - nizh-air-ee-EN

Nigerian (dates from 1860):/nʌɪˈdʒɪərɪən/ - nigh-JEER-ee-uhn

For **Nigeri*e*n** the OED also records /nʌɪˌdʒɛːrɪˈɛn/ - nigh-jair-ee-EN and /naɪˌdʒɛriˈɛn/ - nigh-jair-ee-EN as pronunciations but I have never heard them - the French accent **must** be attempted...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this usage is correct. Niger and Nigeria are different, neighboring countries in Africa.

For both "Niger" and "Nigerien", the emphasis is on the second syllable, though with English speaking audiences this may lead to added confusion because the pronunciation sounds distinctly French. Note below that Britannica lists the emphasis on the second syllable while Cambridge lists it on the first.

Here you can see Brittanica lists "Nigerien" as the adjective form of Niger, with emphasis on the second syllable: https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/Niger

And here you can see that Cambridge also lists it, though they put the emphasis on the first syllable: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/niger

It seems unlikely that this is a strictly local thing as Niger has been a member of the UN since 1960. However I can't speak to why your spell checker thinks it's incorrect.

Comment: It sounds French because it _is_ French!

Comment: @KateBuntingYl Yep! But I more brought that up because lots of English speakers are accustomed to Anglicized pronunciations and may not recognize the French pronunciation of Nigerien.

Comment: Spelling checker on an iPhone really really prefers Nigerian. Which is totally wrong when you talk about Niger.